# Prolog-Crossword constraints

Tags: prolog, logic

I have this fairly simple problem below, that I have to answer:

```
crossword(V1, H1) :- word(V1, X, X, X), word(H1, X, X, X).
```

Would any reasonable word satisfy the constraint in this rule?

My response to seeing this would be to say, that a triple constraint on a three letter word is certainly not "reasonable" and no such word exists to my knowledge.

Would I be correct in saying this?

Comment: you don't show the definition of `word/4` predicate. maybe it takes out every other letter from a word, or every third letter, who knows?

Comment: What do the arguments V1, H1, X stand for? Characters?

Answer (score 0):

No you are not correct.

Until you define the rules for Word/4 the constraints can be anything and there is certainly a set of 3 constraints that can be satisfied.

like

```
word(Var,A,B,C):- A=c,B=a,C=t.
```

Are you sure you are asking the question you want answered?

```
crossword(V1, H1) :- word(V1, X, X, X), word(H1, X, X, X).
```

Means nothing without defining rules (and possibly facts) for word/4